# Highstock Grouping weekly doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use Highstock and got from the server daily data.
But i want to show the data on the graph grouping by week

I found code that work 
http://jsfiddle.net/X5WbN/20/

But it does not work for me

this is my my relevant code

```
var seriasitem = {
                name: this.title,
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                data: tempdata,
                color: ReportBase.colors[inx],
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: [ ['week', [1]] ]
                }


            };
            seriasOptions.push(seriasitem);
```

thanks!
[image]

Comment: Could you setup demo with **not** working code? I mean, in the demo you posted, it works, so there may be something different. For example - do you have enough data to trigger data grouping? If not, then don't forget to set [`forced`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.forced) to true. Additionally, make sure you have included Highstock, not Highcharts.